# Write Multiple Rows in EXCEL (VB) to SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

Would like to be able to write all rows that have data in them to SQL table, with the below I can only export the 1st row. If I add more rows of data and click the Export Button I will only send the first row. Can some one help me script my request?[image]

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.TimeLog" & _
"(EventDate, ID, DeptCode, Opcode, StartTime, FinishTime, Units) " & _
"VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=db\db1;Initial Catalog=Table1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
'Skip the header row
iRowNo = 2

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

iRowNo = 2

With Sheets("Sheet1")
'Loop until empty cell in EventDate
Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""

 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pEventDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, .Cells(iRowNo, 1))
 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pID", adInteger, adParamInput, , .Cells(iRowNo, 2))
 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pDeptCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, .Cells(iRowNo, 3))
 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pOpCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, .Cells(iRowNo, 4))
 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pStartTime", adDBTime, adParamInput, 0, .Cells(iRowNo, 5))
 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pFinishTime", adDBTime, adParamInput, 0, .Cells(iRowNo, 6))
 cmd.Parameters.Append _
 cmd.CreateParameter("pUnits", adInteger, adParamInput, , .Cells(iRowNo, 7))

 cmd.Execute

 iRowNo = iRowNo + 20
 Loop

 MsgBox "Success!"

End With

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `iRowNo = iRowNo + 20` - This means it is only sending data to the database for every 20th row in your worksheet.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @squillman Negative, I would like to send all rows that I have entered data in that resemble the excel snipped photo. As of right now, even if I have 20 rows im only send the 1st

Comment: What happens if you change that line to `iRowNo = iRowNo + 1`?

Comment: I would try squillman's suggestion, and if you're still only seeing one row inserted try adding "cmd.parameters.clear" after cmd is executed each time to make sure the parameters are getting new values each loop

Comment: When I switch to `iRowNo = iRowNo +1` I get an error `Multiple-step OLE DB operator generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.`

Comment: Add the call to `cmd.Parameters.Clear` that @soohoonigan suggested right before you start appending parameters.

Comment: That new error you got can be thrown for a number of reasons, hard to say which it is without knowing your db schema. But things to check are that you aren't trying to insert null into a not-null column, and casting the cell values into the correct datatypes (i.e. text/varchar mismatches). I also see some "time" columns, make sure the strings are being converted to datetimes in your sql correctly if the time columns are date/time datatypes, etc

Comment: @squillman @soohoonigan I did this keeping  `iRowNo = iRowNo +20` and tried with `iRowNo = iRowNo +1` I receive this error `Compile error: Method or data member not found` .Clear

Comment: @soohoonigan Data types are correct. When I test one column it is successful. I copied the column and pasted to several rows to test as well, its essentially the same data...

Comment: Thats is not VB.NET code.  The tags include text to guide you on which to use.

Comment: @Plutonix oops, corrected the tags...thnx